# Is there a PHPmailer parameter to limit re-sends?

Tags: phpmailer

When I use PHPmailer to send to a group of email addresses, it gets caught in a loop and keeps re-sending the email over and over (100 times or more).  It doesn't always do this however.  I can send to 10 or 12 addresses and it works fine.  But a larger list (25 addresses) seems to have trouble. I did find some non-existent email addresses in my list that rebound back to my "from" address mailbox. So I thought that might be the problem. But, I ran a test with just 3 addresses (one non-existent) and it worked as expected (good addresses received the mail, and the bad one was rebounded back to the sender mailbox).  No duplicate emails were sent.

I do use BCC to send my email, but I don't think that should matter.  I'm wondering if maybe there is some parameter I can set for PHPmailer that will tell it not to re-send any emails.  My web hosting site says it is not their server or mail system that is sending these emails, so I'm guessing it is something in PHPmailer.

When my real-life use of PHPmailer doesn't work like it did when I tested it, that makes it very difficult to fix.  Anyone have any suggestions as to why my emails keep getting sent multiple times?

Also, I'd like to know if there's a way to stop PHPmailer, after $mail->Send() has been issued?  I'm getting a little embarrassed with the spam-like behavior of my emails (and my users are getting mad).

My basic code is below.  But, the PHP program code is the same in the cases where it works and doesn't work; it's just the input data that changes.  When it has worked, there were 2 smaller arrays:
emailistAry(1) = array(email1,email2,email3,...email10)  and
emailistAry(2) = array(email1,email2,email3,email4,email5).
When it keeps looping, there are 2 larger arrays:
emailistAry(1) = array(email1,email2,bademail1,email3,email4,bademail2,email5,...email25) and  emailistAry(2) = array(mail26,email27,email28,bademail3,email29,...email50).

I haven't found the exact number that I can process successfully, because it would mean running tests that possibly fill people's mailboxes with endless multiple emails.  No one wants that.

Here's my code:

```
<?php session_start();
  // uses arrays of addresses to send emails to multiple people (with BCC)
  require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head> 
 <link href="../root.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS"/>
 <title> Website Notification  </title>
 <meta http-equiv= "content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>  
 </head>

 <body>
 <div style="top:0;padding:0;width:850px;margin-left:70px;">   
    <?php

    //$emailistAry is gathered from addresses in a database.
    //       it contains 2 arrays of email arrays (multi-dimensional).
    //$emailist_cnt is determined from building above array (currently a 2) 

    $fromaddr = "myaddress@mywebsite.org";
    $toaddr = "groupaddress@mywebsite.com";
    $rplyaddr = "my2address@gmail.com";
    $subject = "--Special Notice--";
    $messageH = "<p style='font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Georgia,\"Times New Roman\";font-size:90%;'> 
        <span style='font-size:120%;color:#336699;'>Greetings HLCA Member!</span> <br/><br/>".  
        "This is my message text....".
        "</p>";
    // Set mail environment variables
    $mail->isSMTP();                                   
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mywebsite.org';                
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            
    $mail->Username = $fromaddr;                   
    $mail->Password = "mypasswd";                       
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                         
    $mail->Port = 587;                                

    // Set mail details that remain constant for every recipient
       $mail->SetFrom($fromaddr);      // mailbox you want email to come from
       $mail->AddAddress($toaddr);     // set recipient group (empty mailbox)
       $mail->AddReplyTo($rplyaddr);   // where reject msgs are sent
           $mail->Subject = make_goodemail($nly,'subj',$subject);
       $mail->Body    = $messageH;

       $goodlist_cnt = $emailist_cnt;
       $max_emails = 25;   // max num emails per list  
       $bcc_out_total = 0; //number emails output with BCC
       $badlist_cnt = 0; 
       $badlist = '';      // save emails that didn't get sent
       $email_badlist = array(); // store email lists that didn't get sent
       $duplist = "";
       $stop_err = false;
       $rcN = 0;  

    // Loop through email arrays and send one at a time (each contains an array of emails).
    // (Note that we do not use the 0 array positions. First entries are in position 1.)

       for ($i=1; $i <= $emailist_cnt; $i+=1) { 
       echo "<p style='margin-top:40px;font-size:120%;'><b> Processing list # ".$i."...</b></p>"; 
       $duplist = "";
           for ($j=1; $j <= $max_emails; $j+=1) {                  
           // add addresses from this list array to BCC parameter,  
           if ($emailistAry[$i][$j] != '') {
           // add current email to BCC for this list (save rc)
           $BCCresult = $mail->AddBCC($emailistAry[$i][$j]);
           if(!$BCCresult) {
              $duplist = $duplist.$emailistAry[$i][$j].", ";
           }
           }
           else {
             $j = $max_emails; //set as end of list
           }
           } // for j loop

       // Loop thru this BCC array and show list on screen. 
       $bccArray = $mail->GetBCCAddresses();
       $bcc_out = 0;  
       echo "<br/>Mail BCC list: ";
       for ($k=0;$k<=$max_emails;$k+=1) {
               if ($bccArray[$k][0] != '') {
          if ($k==0) {                   //first one
                     echo " ".$bccArray[$k][0]; } //no comma
          else {
                     echo ", ".$bccArray[$k][0]; }
          $bcc_out += 1;
               }
           else {
              $k=$max_emails;
               }
       }
       // $bcc_out_total = $bcc_out_total + $bcc_out;
       echo "<br/>BCC count = ".$bcc_out;
       if ($duplist != "") { //print duplicate list  
          echo "<br/> >>Duplicate or invalid emails not included: ".$duplist; 
       }
           //echo "<br/><br/>would send email list here.  webpass=".$webpass;

       // **********  ***********  *************   ************
           // SEND THE MAIL with current BCC list of recipients.
       // Output message indicating if mail for this group was successfully or not. 

       if (!$mail->Send()) { // Send mail, else save emailist.
           // see if connection error, and process accordingly 
           $mail_err = $mail->ErrorInfo;
           $pos = strpos($mail_err,'SMTP connect() failed'); 
           if ($pos===true || $pos >= 0) {
               $addmsg = "(Probably a password error. Try again.) <br/>";
               if ($i == 1) {        // connect error on first try, so 
                  $stop_err = true;  // stop processing cuz this error will continue
                  $rcN = 2;
               }      
           }
           else { 
           $addmsg = ""; 
               $rcN = 1;  //set general error for return
           }
               echo "<h4 style='color:red;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:center;'>
                     Problem sending emails. ".$addmsg." Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo."</h4>";
           echo "<h4 style='color:blue;margin-top:10px;margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:0px;'>Email List #".$i." not sent. </h4>";

           if (!$stop_err) { //other error, so handle and keep going.
               $goodlist_cnt = $goodlist_cnt - 1;  
            //save list in array (as one long string). 
               $badlist_cnt+=1;
               $email_badlist[$badlist_cnt] = implode(",",$emailistAry[$i]); //save as a string
            }
       } //if !Mail-send

       else { // Successful email
           $bcc_out_total = $bcc_out_total + $bcc_out;
           echo "<h4 style='color:blue;margin-top:20px;font-weight:bold;'> 
                 Email group ".$i." sent successfully!  </h4>";
       }

       // Clear cumulative recipient list for next loop
       $mail->clearBCCs();

       if ($stop_err) {
           $i = $emailist_cnt; //set to last list so loop will stop
       }

       } // for i loop

       if ($badlist_cnt > 0)  { // error, but not stop_err, so lists are saved elsewhere.
           $badlist_txt = "<span style='color:red;font-size:80%;'> (".$badlist_cnt." list(s) not sent)</span>";
       //write badlists out to file for fixing and later processing
       include ('includes/memNotifyErrSave.php'); 
       }
       else {
       $badlist_txt = '';
       }

       if ($stop_err) {
       echo "<br/> <h4 style='color:red;margin-top:50px;text-align:center;'> Processing stopped due to serious error!&nbsp; ".
                   "If password error, try again with correct password.<br/><br/>".
               "<span style='font-size:120%;color:blue;font-weight:bold;'>* No emails were sent * </span></h4>";
       }
       else {
           echo "<h4 style='color:blue;font-size:125%;font-weight:bold;margin-top:40px;'>
             Sent this notice to ".$bcc_out_total." unique address(es), using ".$goodlist_cnt." email(s)".$badlist_txt.".</h4>";
       }

       // code for exit/return buttons

    // Clear remaining cumulative lists
    $mail->clearReplyTos();
    $mail->clearAddresses();  
    ?>

  </div>   

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pleas [edit] your question to add some actual code. We can not debug that which we can not see. Voting to close for lack of context.

Comment: so you call send() once and phpmailer ends up delivery X copies to Y people on its own? or are you doing `if(!send(){ send some more}`-type looping yourself?

Comment: Marc B:  I've added some code, so you can see what I do.  But, basically, I loop twice (only 2 lists per run) and each BCC list has 25 or less addresses in it.  So, the send() is only done twice, and each email has no more than 25 recipients.  The program never returns or prints any messages.  It just starts sending the emails over and over (and I receive the bounce back for the bad emails over and over as well).   As I said before, this works fine with 10 addresses in 2 emails.

Comment: @MarcB See above response (I forgot to put the @ in front of your name up there)

Comment: @MattClark please see the code I've added here and hopefully remove the -1 vote.   More testing got the program to choke during a small run. It had 2 emails (1 with 10 addresses, 1 with only 5 addresses).  The # of repetitions seems to correlate with the number of the original addresses.  It's as if it's sending an extra copy of the email for every address in the BCC list (10 copies if 10 addresses, 50 copies if 50 addresses, etc).  I checked my looping code, but can't see anything wrong.  Added echo messages and now my test works. Go figure. Can PHPmailer get messed up if it goes too fast?

Comment: the code's confusing... why are you trying to stuff emails into the mailer, and THEN checking for dupes? it'd easier to just `array_unique()` beforehand. why set sentinel values to fiddle with the loop $i, when you could just `break()` out of the loop? manually incrementing array pointers as well, when you could just have `$arr[] = 'new value'`, yada yada yada. seems like a lot of cargo-cult programming going on in there.

Comment: Hi @MarcB:  I didn't know about the things you suggested, so I will have to try those.  Thanks!  (I'm an old programmer, and breaking from a loop was seen as bad coding.)   But, even with those changes, I don't think it will fix my problem.  I'm at a point now where I can't even create the error in test.  But, I can't send another production email list and have it start over-filling everyone's mailboxes again.  Not sure what else to try, except maybe just sending my emails to only 10 or so people at a time.  Not fun.